# Cloudflare in front of Nginx Reverse - redirect users with certain IP to special page

Tags: nginx, proxypass, cloudflare

I'm running a nginx reverse proxy in front of webpage.
In front of this nginx reverse proxy is also cloudflare reverse proxy running.

Now I'm trying to redirect users with certain ip-addresses to a special webpage.
I'm trying to do this from the nginx reverse proxy, without any luck :/

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

server {
    if ($remote_addr = 1.2.3.4) {
        rewrite ^ http://www.website.com/noscrape.htm;
    }
}

}
```

This is my nginx site conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  bla.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bla.com:80;
    access_log off;
#            proxy_cache            STATIC;
#            proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
#            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
#                                   http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
client_max_body_size 20M;

    }

}
```

Any ideas how I can do that, or is it not possible because of cloudflare?

Comment: You seem to have added a redundant `server` block. The `if` statement needs to be **inside** the `server` block that handles the request, presumably `bla.com`.

Comment: Thank you Richard, that was the problem! It works now!